# For any integer $n$ find $x<n$, and $y<n$ to minimize the natural number $z=xy-n$

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

I need to develop an algorithm for finding the optimal dimensions for setting a set of symbols on a grid (for a typesetting library I'm writing). I need to minimize the number of cells in my grid while having enough to fit $n$ symbols. The next step is to minimize the distance between the two axis sizes $x$ and $y$ so I can choose whether I want a rectangular grid or squarelike grid.

Formally:

> Given a set of symbols $Q$ of cardinality $n$,find $(x,y)\in\mathbb{N^2}$ to minimize $xy-n>0$ and $|x-y|$

I have some intuition that this is an integer programming problem, but I'm not sure exactly how to solve it that way. I can also do some form of gradient descent, but not sure exactly how.

Comment: Not following.  What's specified?  All three integers?  Just $n$?  If $n$ is odd, $n=2k-1$ then take $x=2,y=k$ and then $xy-n=1$ which is as close to $0$ as you allow.  But I don't think that's what you are after.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, $n+1 = 2 \cdot \frac{n+1}{2}.$ If $n$ is even and $n+1$ is prime, you need to go to $n+2 = 2 \cdot \frac{n+2}{2}.$ If $n$ is even and $n+1$ is composite, there is some product $xy = n+1$ with both $x,y>1.$

Comment: Hm, as to the title in the current form, $n\,,x<n$ is not satisfiable. Depending on what your real constrictions are, with big enough $n$, $xy-n$ can be as low as you ever want it to be.

Comment: isnt $x$ and $y$ = $\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil$ ? which minimizes xy-n to a natural amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Agawa001 said in his comment, the solution is rather simple.

$x = ceil(\sqrt{n})$ and $y=floor(\sqrt{n})$